Identify percentage area for each color
I have a set of images like that bellow and I need to identify the the percentage area for each color of column. Some images has the number writed, others doesn't, but I don't need OCR. I really need get the percentage area for each color.
I don't know which technique to use to do it. I can code in R or Python, but I have no idea how to start solve it.


You can get quite far using some relatively standard computer vision techniques, the code below should give you a kickstart. It starts by converting the image to black and white, after which the canny edge detection algorithm is applied to get clean edges of the bar. After this we can try to detect the different areas of the bar to get the contours of the areas.
import cv2
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import requests

url = "https://i.sstatic.net/Jf3wbpG2.jpg"
response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

# convert to black and white image
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)

# erode the image to remove the percentages from the areas
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
img_erosion = cv2.erode(imgray, kernel, iterations=1) 
# apply canny edge detection
canny = cv2.Canny(img_erosion, 100, 200)
# find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(np.array(img), contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

Which gives the following contours:

The final step would be comparing the heights of the areas and calculating their height relative to the total height of the bar.

@Oxbowrce thank you for this north.
